# mongodb условное исключение полей или исключение полей, содержащих null

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Хотелось бы показывать некоторые поля документов, если они будут соответствовать условию, а если нет, то вообще не показывать.

Думал что это можно сделать так:

```
Model.aggregate([
                    {
                        $project: {                                
                            name: {
                                $cond:{
                                    if:{$eq:["$name"," воздух "]},
                                    then:1,
                                    else:0
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ], callback);
```

Но это лишь возвращает вот что:
Модели:

```
[ { name: ' воздух ', _id:1 }, { name: 0, _id:2 }, { name: 0, _id:3 }, { name: , _id:4 } ]
```

Тогда сделал так:

```
Model.aggregate([
                    {
                        $project: {
                            _id:0,
                            $cond:{
                                    if:{$eq:["$name"," воздух "]},
                                    then: {name:1},
                                    else: {name:0}
                                }                                
                        }
                    }
                ], callback);
```

Но это возвращает ошибку.

Почитал, сделал так:

```
 Model.aggregate([
                    {
                        $project: {                                
                            name: {
                                $cond:{
                                    if:{$eq:["$name"," воздух "]},
                                    then:"$name",
                                    else: null
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ], callback);
```

Тогда возвращает вот что:    Модели:

```
[ { name: ' воздух ', _id:1 },
  { name: null, _id:2 },
  { name: null, _id:3 },
  { name: null, _id:4 } ]
```

**Подскажите, как теперь убрать те поля, которые равны null, оставив при этом другие поля? (например, оставив _id)**

Comment: Пожалуйста, вы можете показать образцы документов? Также объясните, что вы пытаетесь сделать здесь, потому что ваш вопрос непонятно

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте убирать поля не в запросе, а в callback-е. В этом вам поможет оператор [delete](http://javascript.ru/delete)

```
function(err,result){
   result=result.map(function(elem){
      for(var key in elem)
         if(elem[key]==null)delete elem[key];
   });
   console.log(result);
}
```

При этом, вероятно, хватит обычного `.find()`, если с использованием `.aggregate()` возникают сложности